# what is the sudo apt-get install pgrouting-workshop command doing?

Tags: 14.04

Well my questions says it all,  am having a difficulty understanding the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install pgrouting-workshop
```

I understand the below part:

```
sudo apt-get install
```

but i don't understand the last part I.E.

```
pgrouting-workshop
```

Is that a package being downloaded ? or a software , where is it being downloaded/fetched from ? Also if i successfully run the above command, how do i check where the folder/package `pgrouting-workshop` is installed ? (i know how to open a directory in ubuntu terminal).

pgrouting-workshop

Answer (score 2):

It installs the package pgrouting-workshop if the PPA **ppa:georepublic/pgrouting** is activated.

You can check which files the package installs by running

```
dpkg -L pgrouting-workshop
```